# How to read content in image and pdf in alfresco

Tags: ocr, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to know how to search content from image and PDF in alfresco using OCR integration
please let me know the steps how can i do this??Using Kofax or EpheSoft scanning software..
Let me know the steps...

I tried out https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/kofax-amp-install.html link but failed to install amp files..
For ex:content is search from image or pdf
How is it possible?

please help me..

Thanks in advanced

Comment: one more thing i want to edit.. i am using 4.2 alfresco version and os linux 32bit..

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear so her it goes.

First OCR is not something Alfresco does, but Kofax/Ephesoft.

1. Check if Kofax/Ephesoft does OCR right. Save the PDF manually in Alfresco and check if it's searchable.
2. Install the Kofax AMP
3. Install the Alfresco releasescript in Kofax
4. Connect to Alfresco from Kofax via the releasescript (define a root folder to scan to)
5. Scan to Alfresco and all should be well.

For Ephesoft, follow this http://addons.alfresco.com/featured/document-capture-ephesoft

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can you please give me link from where can i download this kofax amp and all??